# “Disk drive for /boot/efi is not ready yet or not present” after reinstalling Windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

There are a number of questions with very similar titles on this site but none of them really helped me. If I missed something, please let me know.

So here is my story:

My laptop was shipped with Win 8.1 (UEFI mode). I installed Ubuntu 14.04 later and told it to boot from its root partition. So I had two bootable partitions and usually just booted the Ubuntu one as I could also choose Windows in the grub menu. Some days ago I reinstalled Win 8.1 and as expected was not able to boot Ubuntu anymore. The Ubuntu partition was set unbootable. I then just installed grub2 on the boot partition created by Windows and did a `sudo os-prober` and a `sudo update-grub`. Now when booting from the Win boot partition grub shows up and I can choose between the operating systems and everything works fine. The only thing is that when I choose Ubuntu I now get the message

```
Disk drive for /boot/efi is not ready or not present.
Continue waiting or press s to skip or m for manual recovery.
```

If I press <kbd>s</kbd> Ubuntu boots normally and works fine, but the message is sort of annoying and I would also like to understand where it comes from.

I guess I screwed up a bit when I decided to not boot from the Ubuntu partition anymore but from the Windows partition. I still have the `/boot` folder on my Ubuntu partition. Just re setting the `boot` flag on the Ubuntu partition would have probably made everything work as before, right?

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Here is a screenshot from gparted:

[image]

**EDIT:**

The problem was simply that the serial number of `/dev/sdb2` in `/etc/fstab` was wrong. Apparently it was changed by reinstalling Windows. After fixing that everything works fine. I accepted Rods answer because it helped me figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, EFI boot loaders are ordinary files that reside on the [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which is mounted at `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu. When an OS installs an EFI boot loader, it also creates an entry in NVRAM that points to its boot loader. You can usually get a boot menu showing these entries when you start the computer. This contrasts with BIOS, where boot loaders are stored in the first sector of the hard disk and (often) in the first few sectors of certain partitions, which are often marked with a "boot flag." Thus, in BIOS, it makes sense to refer to a *boot disk* or a *boot partition,* but in EFI, these phrases are ambiguous or misleading; you've got *boot files* and *NVRAM boot entries* instead. Also, EFI does not use a "boot flag." Confusingly, libparted (and hence `parted` and GParted) abuse the term "boot flag" to refer to the type code for the ESP; and setting this type code inappropriately can cause serious problems. I point all this out because your question is riddled with BIOS-centric terminology and, reading between the lines, it sounds as if you don't understand this critical difference between BIOS-mode and EFI-mode booting. Such misunderstandings often lead to people making serious mistakes, up to and including trashing their installations, so it's important that you learn a bit about this. For more on such differences, see [Adam Williamson's blog post](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) on how EFI-mode booting works.

Your problem, though, is not directly related to any of this. Rather, you're unable to mount your ESP (`/dev/sdb2` in your case) in Ubuntu. This symptom often results from the Windows "Fast Startup" feature. (Note that many EFIs have an unrelated feature with a similar name. It's the *Windows* feature that's relevant.) You can disable Fast Startup in Windows 8/8.1 as described [here,](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) or in Windows 10 as described [here.](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) (Lots of other pages also describe how to do this.) In some cases you may need to disable the Windows hibernate feature, too, as described [here.](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html)

Once you've made these Windows changes, the ESP should become mountable in Ubuntu again. If it doesn't, you may need to back it up and re-create it. You may be able to force it to mount in Ubuntu by mounting it explicitly at the command line; or you can back it up in an EFI shell or in Windows. With that done, create a fresh filesystem on it and restore the backed-up files. You may then need to modify the `/etc/fstab` entry for `/boot/efi` to identify it with its new serial number (called a UUID in `/etc/fstab`, although it really isn't that). You can type `sudo blkid /dev/sda2` to learn the serial number ("UUID") after you create a fresh filesystem on it.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're right, I was indeed not aware of these differences. So I can only have one ESP per hard disk right? Before I reinstalled Windows I had two boot entries to choose from in the boot menu so this means that I simply had to NVRAM entries then, right? I will try what you suggested in the evening today and let you know if it works.

Comment: The problem was somewhere else altogether. For some reason the "UUID" of `/dev/sdb2` was changed by reinstalling Windows. I fixed that in `/etc/fstab` and now everything works fine.

Comment: The EFI spec is quite clear that's it's legal to have multiple ESPs, even on a single hard disk. In practice, though, some tools may become confused by this. The Windows installer (at least through Windows 7; I've not checked later versions) is one such program. Although it's legal to have multiple ESPs, the usual practice is to share one among multiple OSes. You can have multiple NVRAM entries pointing to several boot loaders on a single (or multiple) ESPs. EFI is very flexible in this respect.